# Ctrl + up/down arrow produce an output in my terminal (alacritty). Any ideas where it is coming from?

Tags: linux, terminal, alacritty

I'm running the garuda/sway distro and I get the following output in the alacritty 0.10.1 terminal when pressing:

Ctrl + UP Arrow => [1;5A]

Ctrl + DOWN Arrow => [1;5B]

One other odd little detail is that it seems to shift the cursor back one place after pasting the value... so that pressing:

Ctrl + UP then Ctrl + DOWN => [1;5A[1;5B]]

The config just has a few colour changes in it. I installed another terminal as a test (st) and I don't see the same thing there.

Does anybody recognise those codes or have any thoughts on where these are coming from? ... or perhaps a general process for finding out?
Can anybody confirm if they get the same thing running alacritty?

UPDATE:
For anyone finding this, see accepted answer and comment below but the TLDR is I think this is more specifically a fish shell issue. I dont get the issue with bash and alacritty. I do see it with fish and st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those *are* the actual codes for Ctrl+Up and Ctrl+Down in terminals. They show up because you're sending them to a program that doesn't recognize them.

(More precisely, Ctrl+Up is `ESC` `[` `1` `;` `5` `A` in most terminals, though it might be `ESC` `O` `A` in some modes or in some terminals like rxvt.)

Line editing and cursor movement aren't implemented by your terminal – they're implemented by the shell, or whatever other program is currently active *in* the terminal. (For example, Bash uses its own line-editing library called 'readline', Zsh has its own.) Whenever you press a cursor key, Bash receives this kind of key sequence, figures out the new cursor location, then prints another sequence asking the terminal to actually move the cursor there.

Generally, only interactive shells or full-screen programs (like text editors) are supposed to recognize special keys, but other programs reading from stdin usually won't, so e.g. if you run `cat` it's completely normal that it won't recognize arrow keys at all.

However, if programs such as Bash don't recognize them, then your system may be missing the *terminfo* database for your terminal (which lets programs know what codes correspond to what keys). For example, Alacritty sets $TERM to the value `alacritty`, so Bash will try to read `/usr/share/terminfo/a/alacritty` for the key definitions – this file should come with the 'ncurses' package.

So make sure the terminfo definition for alacritty is installed (especially if you're SSHing to a remote system), or optionally try configuring it to export `xterm-256color` instead [like discussed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597445/why-would-i-set-term-to-xterm-256color-when-using-alacritty).

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, I'm now thinking this has nothing to do with alacritty and is in fact fish shell related. I switched to bash in alacritty to test after reading your readline explanation and it's not happening there. I do have alacritty, alacritty+common and alacritty-direct under /usr/share/terminfo/a - so i assume that's OK. And I'm not sshing at this time, this is happening locally. I think you have answered my question as it stands. I will do a little more digging now I have a better understanding. But do feel free to reply if you have any further suggestions.

Comment: It's a combination of both. One issue I did not mention is that terminfo doesn't quite describe everything; the input parsing to some extent still depends on the program making assumptions. It could very well be that e.g. fish looks for the word `xterm` specifically (most terminals today, alacritty included, are xterm-compatible). It wouldn't be the first time.